# C# Change color of one character in a text box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

C# - WPF  :
how can I change the color of just one character in a text box ? 
example : Word Hello, Color of H becomes Red

Comment: use a richtextbox: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-richtextbox/

Comment: I think it's funny how most of my questions get downvoted to oblivion, but this guy hardly even forms a full sentence and gets +4. Was Stackoverflow actually nice to people in 2013?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not do this with a textbox, but you can use a richtextbox:
[WPF RichTextBox Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-richtextbox/)

```
var textRange = MyRichTextBox.Selection;
var start = MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart;
var startPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(0);
var endPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(1);
textRange.Select(startPos, endPos);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use richtexbox like below: You can even change backcolor for a particular character as well

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = characterStartIndex;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 1;
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```